# Опечатки в резолюциях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В текстах резолюций на закрытие присутствуют следующие опечатки:

1. [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95035/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E):

   > Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста задайте новый вопрос.

   Не хватает запятой после "пожалуйста".
2. [Не по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98539/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC):

   > Те, кто, голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующую причину:

   Лишняя запятая после "кто".
3. [Требует правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557132/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5):

   > что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

   Пробел внутри "т.д".

   > Если этот вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам, изложенными в Справке, отредактируйте его.

   Должно быть "изложенным".

Comment: Про "и т. д." спорно. [Википедия, например, использует неразрывные пробелы.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD:%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B4)

Comment: @D-side вона как. Не знал об этом.